# How to use user-defined python objects in MATLAB?

Tags: python, matlab

I have a class in Python that has resources (such as sockets). I would like to use the class in MATLAB. It is important for me to ensure that the python object will continue to hold his resources. To test how MATLAB will handle this, I created the following class in Python:

```
class Klaus:
    def __init__(self, id):
        self.id = id
        print "klaus::ctor::id={}".format(self.id)

    def __del__(self):
        print "klaus::dtor::id={}".format(self.id)
```

And here is my MATLAB code:

```
klaus = py.klaus.Klaus(42);
for i = 1:5
    disp("klaus says " + klaus.id);
end
delete(klaus);
```

MATLAB output seems to be in a very unclear order:

```
klaus::ctor::id=42.0
klaus::dtor::id=42.0
klaus says 42
klaus says 42
klaus says 42
klaus says 42
klaus says 42
klaus::dtor::id=42.0
```

I excepted that the ctor will be first, following by "klaus says" and the dtor will be in the end. A simple test written in python produces the excepted behavior. But I don't understand why the order is different in MATLAB.

edit: I failed at copy-pasting

Comment: Why does the destructor show a different ID value than the other calls? I think this might be a different object being destructed. Add a `delete(klaus)` at the end of your MATLAB script, see if the right destructor is being called. Currently your MATLAB script doesn't delete the object at all.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The different ID was copy-paste failure. Please see the updated text that includes your suggested edit.

Comment: Another thing to try: have the destructor reset the ID value. Then you can see if the first destructor call was to a copy of the object or if the same object is actually being deleted twice. You certainly hit on some strange behavior IMO.

Comment: I can reproduce this, honestly feels like a bug